# Docker-Compose ParserError: while parsing a block mapping

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I'm building Multi-org fabric but when I run command `docker-compose up -d`
it gives below error

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 130, column 3
```

Below is the `docker-compose.yaml`.

```
version: '2'

networks:
  basic:

services:
  ca.main.tcloud.kpn.org:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca: x86_64-1.0.6
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/c59a4aad4207795c6ccaf6301425732c287b976bcc291e3e398c9d74f0eb4774_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.main.tcloud.kpn.org
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer.main.tcloud.kpn.org:
    container_name: orderer.main.tcloud.kpn.org
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer: x86_64-1.0.6
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/main.tcloud.kpn.org/orderers/orderer.main.tcloud.kpn.org/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org/peers/peer0.crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerCrm
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ebs.main.tcloud.kpn.org/peers/peer0.ebs.main.tcloud.kpn.org/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerEbs
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/lsp.main.tcloud.kpn.org/peers/peer0.lsp.main.tcloud.kpn.org/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerLsp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/delivery.main.tcloud.kpn.org/peers/peer0.delivery.main.tcloud.kpn.org/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerDelivery
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
    networks:
      - basic

  peer0.crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org:
    container_name: peer0.crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer: x86_64-1.0.6
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=crmMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdbcrm:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org/peers/peer0.crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - couchdbcrm
    networks:
      - basic
  peer0.ebs.main.tcloud.kpn.org:
    container_name: peer0.ebs.main.tcloud.kpn.org
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer: x86_64-1.0.6
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.ebs.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ebsMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.ebs.main.tcloud.kpn.org:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=kpn_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdbebs:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ebs.main.tcloud.kpn.org/peers/peer0.ebs.main.tcloud.kpn.org/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ebs.main.tcloud.kpn.org/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - couchdbebs
    networks:
      - basic

  peer0.lsp.main.tcloud.kpn.org:
    container_name: peer0.lsp.main.tcloud.kpn.org
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer: x86_64-1.0.6
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.lsp.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=lspMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.lsp.main.tcloud.kpn.org:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=kpn_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdblsp:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9053:7053
    volumes:
       - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
       - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/lsp.main.tcloud.kpn.org/peers/peer0.lsp.main.tcloud.kpn.org/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
       - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/lsp.main.tcloud.kpn.org/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
       - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - couchdblsp
    networks:
      - basic

  peer0.delivery.main.tcloud.kpn.org:
    container_name: peer0.delivery.main.tcloud.kpn.org
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer: x86_64-1.0.6
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.delivery.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=deliveryMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.delivery.main.tcloud.kpn.org:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=net_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdbdelivery:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 10051:7051
      - 10053:7053
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/delivery.main.tcloud.kpn.org/peers/peer0.delivery.main.tcloud.kpn.org/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/delivery.main.tcloud.kpn.org/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
      - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - couchdbdelivery
    networks:
      - basic

  couchdbcrm:
    container_name: couchdbcrm
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb: x86_64-1.0.6
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - basic
  couchdbebs:
    container_name: couchdbebs
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb: x86_64-1.0.6
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5985:5984
    networks:
      - basic
  couchdblsp:
    container_name: couchdblsp
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb: x86_64-1.0.6
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5986:5984
    networks:
      - basic

  couchdbdelivery:
    container_name: couchdbdelivery
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb: x86_64-1.0.6
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5987:5984
    networks:
      - basic

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools: x86_64-1.0.6
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=crmMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org/users/Admin@crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    networks:
        - basic
    depends_on:
      - orderer.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - peer0.crm.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - peer0.ebs.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - peer0.lsp.main.tcloud.kpn.org
      - peer0.delivery.main.tcloud.kpn.org
```

I have also validated online with YAML validator but it's showing correct YAML so I'm not sure where its going wrong. I have checked if there are any tabs present or not but there is not tab.

Comment: Which validator did you use? There are some really useless validators out there, e.g.  the one at codebeautify.org. In YAML, you're not allowed to  have a value indicator followed by a space (i.e. `: `) in a plain scalar and you do in `hyperledger/fabric-tools: x86_64-1.0.6`

Comment: Thank you @Anthon . Yeah I use condebeautify.org. I will never use that again ;)  I removed space it's working now.

Answer (score 3):

Your image declarations contain invalid spaces:

```
image: hyperledger/fabric-ca: x86_64-1.0.6
---------------------here----^
```

Delete it!

Comment: Thank you @ozlevka it worked after removing space. But not able to get why line number is different in error message.

Comment: Yaml parser bags :)